# How to get data as array in view?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeIgniter, I have a query in my model as
`return $query = $this->db->get('users')->result();`

and I have passed the result from controller to view as 
`$data['users'] = $this->admin_login->get_users();`

But I am not able to print the passed data properly in my view, because it is in standard class object.

So far I have tried

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    print_r $user;
}
```

and the result I am getting is

```
stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 1
    [user_name] => mujju
    [email] => mujahed.akas@gmail.com
    [mobile] => 9021444578
)

stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 2
    [user_name] => mujahed
    [email] => s.mujju786@gmail.com
    [mobile] => 8989898989
)

stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 3
    [user_name] => akas
    [email] => s.mujju786@yahoo.com
    [mobile] => 6545789878
)

stdClass Object
(
    [user_id] => 4
    [user_name] => sayyed
    [email] => s.mujahed90@gmail.com
    [mobile] => 654597879686
)
```

and what I am expecting is to use something like `$user['user_id']` , `$user['user_name']` etc. in foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access a property of an object like this: `$user->user_id`

Optionally you can pass the data as an array instead of an object to the view:

```
return $query = $this->db->get('users')->result_array();
```

Passing the data from the controller to the view works like this:

```
$this->load->view('your_view', $data);
```

More information in the [user guide](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html?highlight=data#adding-dynamic-data-to-the-view)

Comment: Can I pass data from controller to view as array? How?

Comment: @MujahedAKAS added an example ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach($users as $user):
    echo 'user id :' . $user->user_id  . '<br>Username : '. $user->user_name. '<br>Email : ' . $user->email . '<br>Mobile : '. $user->mobile;
endforeach;
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Thanx, For quick reply @Birendra.